# What percentage swing needed to win a vote?

Tags: statistics

(This seemed like a no-brainer, but I'm throwing my hands up...)

Australia is having a national "postal survey" about same-sex marriage.

- The options on the ballot paper are "Yes" and "No", but voting is not compulsory.
- The survey is being conducted over 8 weeks during which eligible voters can return their response.
- At the end of the third week, 60% of voters have returned their response.
- Exit-polling indicates of those who have already voted, 60% voted "Yes" and 40% voted "No".

**Question**:  All other things being equal (e.g. early/late responders no indication of which way they vote) what % of the remaining 40% who haven't returned their response would need to vote "No" in order to achieve parity with the "Yes" vote (here's the kicker...) taking into account that not all eligible voters will ultimately return their ballots?

Is this work-outable?

Comment: what has been tried? we aren't just a question and answer site.

Comment: Out of $0.6$ of those who have voted, $0.6$ voted 'Yes' and $0.4$ voted 'No'. So in order to calculate the percent of people in the entire population, what operation do you have to use?

Comment: You can only work out concrete numbers if you are able assume something more about how many eligible voters will ultimately return their ballots. "Not all" tells us next to nothing: "not all" can be anything from 0% to 99.999%.

Comment: @all.  I can work it out assuming a 100% return rate,  but I came unstuck trying to factor in the non - responses. I dunno, I thought there might be a way of estimating from "60% at 3/8ths of the way in" what the overall response rate would be by week 8.

Comment: okay what's the minimum percentage of returns overall that are needed for the rebound win ?? that's calculable.

Comment: Thanks everyone... thinking about the comments & the answer below (i.e. if I go quiet for a while it's not that your help wasn't appreciated!)

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee "what's the minimum percentage of returns overall that are needed for the rebound win"  -  Good q'n. Never occurred to me...

Assuming the population of 1,000 people...
1000*.6 = 600 Returned / 400 Unreturned (as of now) ... 
600*.6 = 360 Yes / 240 No ... 
360-240 = 120 more No's required for parity (.12 of 1000) ... 
.12+.6 = 72% turnout required at *minimum* if 100% of remaining votes returned are a No (and the rest just unreturned) ...

(Penguino below came to  85%.  Did I go awry?)

Comment: I have to be honest, it’s hard to infer what the questions wants to be held constant and what they want us to vary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the final vote turn-out was approximately 100%, then the remaining voters would have to split approximately 35% Yes, to 65% No to swing the total to No.

If the final vote turn-out was approximately 72%, then the remaining voters would have to split approximately 0% Yes, to 100% No to swing the total to No.

If the final vote turn-out was less than approximately 72%, then there is no way to swing the total to No.

**(Off-topic-note: I can only hope that the referendum is binding and Australia can finally join the 20th century in this matter).**

Comment: not that answer I get unfortunately for me I guess.

Comment: Ok, given a bit of prodding from @RoddyMacPhee I came to 72% minimum turnout as well, so accepting this answer on that basis.  Thanks everyone.